# Value of UIBackgroundTaskInvalid is?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I read from the header file (UIApplication.h):

```
typedef NSUInteger UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier;
UIKIT_EXTERN const UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier UIBackgroundTaskInvalid  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
```

It seems that UIBackgroundTaskInvalid is just an ordinary NSUInteger with a given value. Now that I'm writing code that has to be compatible with jailbreaking iOS 3.1.3 (where UIBackgroundTaskInvalid is not defined yet). I might need the real value behind it. Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with

```
#if !defined UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier
   // Pre iOS 4 Fallback
#endif
```

---

The sample above only checks the value on compile time. If you need these kind of checks on run-time you can check this great [article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html).

Comment: Thanks Henrik. The thing is, my binary needs to be compatible with both iOS 4.x and 3.x. Will #if/#endif still work in my case?

Comment: added some further information. just found this great article :)